# SQL Server stored procedure execution time

Tags: sql-server

Trying to time the total execution of this stored procedure but I keep getting 0 ms as the output. I've tried changing it to microseconds, nanoseconds, etc. but still get 0ms. Any suggestions?

```
USE [zzz]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spzzz]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartTime DateTime2
    SET @StartTime = SYSUTCDATETIME()

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @num1 AS INT
    DECLARE @num2 AS INT
    DECLARE @num3 AS INT
    DECLARE @AddedNum AS INT

    SET @num1 = 1
    SET @num2 = 1
    SET @num3 = @num1 + @num2 
    SET @AddedNum = 0

    -- Loop while @num1, @num2, @num3 are all less than 4_000_000
    WHILE @num1 < 4000000 AND @num2 < 4000000 AND @num3 < 4000000
    BEGIN
        SET @AddedNum = @AddedNum + @num3
        SET @num1 = @num2 + @num3
        SET @num2 = @num3 + @num1
        SET @num3 = @num1 + @num2
    END

    PRINT @AddedNum

    PRINT 'Time taken was ' + CAST(DATEDIFF(millisecond, @StartTime, SysUTCDateTime()) AS varchar) + 'ms'
END
```

Comment: Seems that bit of code is really fast! It works if you put a simple query in there.

Comment: I'm not sure how optimisation works in SQL Server, but if that was a compiled language I'd expect the compiler to optimise it pretty heavily (possibly all the way down to the equivalent of `PRINT 4613732`). Perhaps the query analyser is doing something similar.

Comment: The while loop only executes `11` times. Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: @Squirrel has got it. If I change the loop so that a number is merely incremented 4000000 times, it takes over 1000ms to complete.

Comment: I would recommend using extended events to measure the run-time of stored procs.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it was just too fast. I was expecting it to run quickly, just didn't expect it to run THAT quickly. Thanks!

Comment: According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sysutcdatetime-transact-sql, the precision of SYSUTCDATETIME is 100 nanoseconds, so anything less than that will probably show as 0 even when the datepart is nanoseconds.